# Detecting current rotation with Paper.js

Tags: javascript, game-physics, paperjs

I'm making a small shoot 'em up game with [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org),
but I'm unable to find that Paperscript provides any way to get the current rotation
of my group of items.

In the code beneath, rotating 'circlegroup' with Q and E keys, should affect the WASD navigation, moving the item in the direction that the 'nose' of the object is currently pointing at. I figure that I need to get the current rotation of my items in order to
affect the navigation. Does Paper.js provide any way to do this?

[You can see/edit the Papersketch here](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/jdBBb4IwFAfwr/LCBcgQdckuGE4u2WGXJTuKh9o+paG+ulJkxPjdB+iQ6JQlvbzX5vd/rweH2BadyPnM0PLUCRyuRVOv5IZLwxVCDIQlfDCbhvO24x0SAjBMyCKPppOgqdZSqblW2kTgbgxWbtvd6VxaqSkCr34HzxO/beeokFsUEVhTYEJHf5ZQQvmWKfWv0JebzJViPHM7as8MnCSuyTJJaOBsvhld7E4aT6USBila9KID6FZfXi2xl1iGHMmi6ZL6WZuGfhADi6uZlh2zLog3IaDpHatXXZKH+zrJh5aQ61MZZlhBHINbuucb6GeHv7OGFYximE5mzZPjnwIbEL4HhXxwhqcBQQzOMCR8XQSA8RhSrQSI+vtuVaMts+hN/Qcc3uPKu97oAtbHOf4A)

```
bigcircle = new Path.Circle({
  radius:10,
  fillColor: 'grey',
  position: (10, 20),
  selected: true
});

smallcircle = new Path.Circle({
  radius:5,
  fillColor: 'black'
});

var circlecontainer  = new Group({
  children:[smallcircle, bigcircle],
  position: view.center
});


var circlegroup = new Group({
  children: [circlecontainer]
});

function onKeyDown(event) {
  if(event.key == 'w') {
    circlegroup.position.y -= 10;
  }
  if(event.key == 'a') {
    circlegroup.position.x -= 10;
  }
  if(event.key == 's') {
    circlegroup.position.y += 10;
  }
  if(event.key == 'd') {
    circlegroup.position.x += 10;
  }
  if(event.key == 'q') {
      // hold down
    circlegroup.rotate(1);
  }
  if(event.key == 'e') {
      // hold downw
    circlegroup.rotate(-1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no rotation property stored per object. You'll need to define it per object or class yourself. Take a look at the Paperoids game included in the [Github Repository](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/tree/master/examples/Games) for a more detailed example.

Answer (score 7):

There actually is a rotation property now, as written about here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/paperjs/Vwp5HbTo9W0

In order for this to work, you currently need to set #transformContent to false (also described in the above post). This will soon become the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this question in 2017... there is a Path.position property http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#rotation