# Scaling Raster with Paper.js using Tween.js

Tags: javascript, paperjs, tweenjs

I'm think I'm having a [similar issue as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20701819/detecting-current-rotation-with-paper-js) in that I can not work out (or know if it exists) whereby I can get access to the scaling applied to a given object (in my instance, a raster).

I need to know this so I can animate the scaling via Tween.js.

Anyone have any ideas or know if indeed it is possible to find out the current scaling applied to a raster (or any) object?

I thought it was an issue with Rasters so I tried tweening the scale property of a Path and then a Group and I couldn't get access to the values in order to animate it.

Because I am using Tween.js I can not simply use the object.scale(value) function.

UPDATE

I even tried applying an arbitrary (animated) number to the scale function and it failed to work... i.e.:

```
object.scale( 0 );
object.arbitraryNumber = 0;
createjs.Tween.get( object )
    .to( { arbitraryNumber:1 } , 1000, createjs.Ease.getPowInOut(2) )
    .addEventListener( "change", function( event ) {
       event.target.target.scale( event.target.target.arbitraryNumber);
} );
```

Although this did not work, when the same approach was applied to the x position of the object, it animated fine.

Is there anything that needs to be flagged in order to update scaling of an object?

Answer (score 1):

When calling [Item.scale()](http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#scale-scale) method on each frame with values from 0 to 1, you are actually scaling down item exponentially because each call scales the item relatively to the previous value.
What you want to do is animate the [Item.scaling](http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#scaling) property instead.

You also have to know that by default, PaperJS use global coordinates system and apply every transformations directly to points.
You can change this behavior by setting [Item.applyMatrix](http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#applymatrix) property to `false`.
Doing this, scale change will affect item matrix instead of affecting points coordinates and you will be able to animate it as you expect.

Here is simple [Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/TU/NCsIwDH6V0IvzhzIPXhRPgjdB8Og8xJppWU1HVjdFfHfbqWAggfD95MtTMV5JzdWuomAuaqKMP6W9RQFjxTiCXy2BqYMthote9UjWWuq0IQ4kE5jlw0UhBX9UurTOrbzz0isHXpDPNPhnYF27xwaD2HtklOga6uHU5Y1NsJ7B81piwozaeGaYoGcaKc/XpjHoLJ+jxSZFayxnUxhDL9DG3zjACHKdzz7xXvHHoxBWtbccGjXfH15v) of a scale animation:

```
var circle         = new Path.Circle(view.center, 50);
circle.fillColor   = 'orange';
circle.applyMatrix = false;

function onFrame(event)
{
    circle.scaling = Math.sin(1 + event.count * 0.05);
}
```

You should be able to transpose this example to your Tween.js context easily.